# Contact Form - having difficulty connecting

Tags: php, html

I have contact form from a purchased template.

I entered the host, port, username, and password. And on the contact page `$(window).load` script within the 'head'. I'm not having any luck connecting the form.

Script on contact page. I've even tried replacing '#'(ownerEmail) with the email address.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $().UItoTop({ easingType: 'easeOutQuart' });
 }); 

 $(window).load(function(){
    $('#form').TMForm({
        ownerEmail:'#' 

    })
 })

 </script>
```

**MailHandler.php**

```
//SMTP server settings  
$host = "smtp.host.com";
$port = "587";
$username = "";
$password = "";


$messageBody = "";

if($_POST['name']!='false'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>Visitor: ' . $_POST["name"] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['email']!='false'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>Email Address: ' . $_POST['email'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}else{
    $headers = '';
}
if($_POST['state']!='false'){       
    $messageBody .= '<p>State: ' . $_POST['state'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['phone']!='false'){       
    $messageBody .= '<p>Phone Number: ' . $_POST['phone'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}   
if($_POST['fax']!='false'){     
    $messageBody .= '<p>Fax Number: ' . $_POST['fax'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['message']!='false'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>Message: ' . $_POST['message'] . '</p>' . "\n";
}

if($_POST["stripHTML"] == 'true'){
    $messageBody = strip_tags($messageBody);
}

if($host=="" or $username=="" or $password==""){
    $owner_email = $_POST["owner_email"];
    $headers = 'From:' . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n" . 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
    $subject = 'A message from your site visitor ' . $_POST["name"];

    try{
        if(!mail($owner_email, $subject, $messageBody, $headers)){
            throw new Exception('mail failed');
            }else{
            echo 'mail sent';
        }
        }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage() ."\n";
    }
}else{  
    require_once 'Mail.php';

    $to = $_POST["owner_email"];
    $subject = 'A message from your site visitor ' . $_POST["name"];
    $headers = array (
    'From' => 'From:' . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n" . 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n",
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject);

    $smtp = Mail::factory(
                'smtp',
                array (
                    'host' => $host,
                    'port' => $port,
                    'auth' => true,
                    'username' => $username,
                    'password' => $password));

    $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $messageBody);

    try{
        if(PEAR::isError($mail)){
            echo $mail->getMessage();
            }else{
            echo 'mail sent';
        }
        }catch(Exception $mail){
        echo $mail->getMessage() ."\n";
    }
}   
?>
```

Form

```
  <form id="form">

                      <div class="success_wrapper">
                      <div class="success-message">Contact form submitted</div>
                      </div>
                      <label class="name">
                      <input type="text" placeholder="Name" data-constraints="@Required @JustLetters" />
                      <span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
                      <span class="error-message">*This is not a valid name.</span>
                      </label>

                      <label class="email">
                      <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" data-constraints="@Required @Email" />
                      <span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
                      <span class="error-message">*This is not a valid email.</span>
                      </label>
                       <label class="phone">
                          <input type="text" placeholder="Phone" data-constraints="@Required @JustNumbers"/>
                          <span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
                          <span class="error-message">*This is not a valid phone.</span>
                          </label>
                      <label class="message">
                      <textarea placeholder="Message" data-constraints='@Required @Length(min=20,max=999999)'></textarea>
                      <span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
                      <span class="error-message">*The message is too short.</span>
                      </label>
                      <div>
                      <div class="clear"></div>
                      <div class="btns">
                      <a href="#" data-type="submit" class="btn">Send message</a></div>
                      </div>
                      </form>
```

Comment: Can we see the form HTML please?

Comment: I've added the form.

Comment: The script lets anyone send mail to any address they choose by manipulating the target email address client-side. You shouldn't be using this script before at least that is fixed.

Comment: If you aren't using `AJAX` then your `<form>` element will need an `action` attribute which links to the php file. See example: `<form action="/includes/scripts/upload-csv.php" method="post">`

Comment: which template you have purchased?

Comment: templatemonster, 47408